# Can't listen to hover (etc) events after creating divs using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I generate some divs using this

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<div class="colorBox" id="box'+i+'"></div>';
```

The problem I'm running into is that catching a hover event

```
$(".colorBox").hover(function(){
    alert("!");
});
```

Won't work after doing that. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
To be more clear, check this out: http://graysonearle.com/test/16_t.html

I need to be able to have hover events happen after changing innerHTML that happen dynamically and many times. So like after changing the number of columns, the hover effect needs to work.

THANKS TO CHOSEN ANSWER:
For those in the future that might want to do something similar, my code looks like this now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
      ++mouseDown;
    }
    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
      --mouseDown;
    }

    $(document).on("mouseenter",".colorBox",function(){
        if(mouseDown){
            var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
            var clicked = clicked.substring('box'.length);
            next_color(clicked);
        }       
        $(this).css("border-color","#ff0");
        }).on("mouseleave", ".colorBox", function() {
        $(this).css("border-color","#aaa");
    });

    $(document).on("click",".colorBox",function(){
        var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
        var clicked = clicked.substring('box'.length);
        next_color(clicked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whenever we update DOM from server side code or client side code.
For EX. DIV we are updating then it will not work with events we loaded before if we load that partial data.

so for this in document ready
code like this.
if you are using jquery 1.7+
then code like

```
$(document).on("hover",".colorBox",function(){
    alert("Hi it will load after partial div update as well");
});

$(document).delegate(".colorBox","hover",function(){
    alert("Hi it will load after partial div update as well");
});
```

and if you are using jquery 1.6 or less then that.

then use

```
$(".colorBox").live("hover",function(){
    alert("Hi it will load after partial div update as well");
});
```

http://oscarotero.com/jquery/

Comment: It is very well detailed in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) as well.

Comment: How can I determine which colorBox is being hovered, and apply something like $(colorBox).border color change? Because before I was using $(this).do_whatever

Comment: $(document).on("hover",".colorBox",function(){
    $(this).do_whatever//this will work same as it was working before for you
});

Comment: OIC, it just doesn't seem to let me do the hoverOff method I was using earlier..  $(document).on("hover",".colorBox",function(){
  $(this).css("border-color","#ff0");
  },function(){
  $(this).css("border-color","#aaa");

 }); ... any way around this?

Comment: for this you need to do like this.
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function(){ 
//this will work as hover in

 }, 
   mouseleave: function(){ //this will work as hover out}
 },".colorBox");

Answer (score 1):

First, as you're using jQuery your first code could be simplified using the below function.

```
$('#container').append('<div class="colorBox" id="box'+i+'"></div>');
```

Second I think this is because you haven't declared the hover-off function.

```
 $(".colorBox").hover(
       function(){
          alert("On");
       }
    );
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EhNKM/1/)

Comment: Without the second parameter, the passed function is attached to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2).

Comment: ahh ok have checked and updated answer... even without the the document ready it seems to be working. please see fiddle.

Comment: Yes, your fiddle's JS is set to have an `onLoad` wrapper added automatically. `onload`, on DOM ready or right before `</body>` is technically the same thing in this aspect (obv onload is different in that it won't fire until all resources are fully loaded including images, but that's out of the scope of the question).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your hover code AFTER injecting your divs. Jquery doesn't automatically listen to dom changes, so if you hook all your colorBoxes in `$(document).ready(){...}` and then insert a new div, nothing will ever happen.

So this works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<div class="colorBox" id="box'+i+'"></div>';
    }
    $(".colorBox").hover(function(){
        alert("!");
    });
}
```

Comment: you can also add "live" listeners with `$.on`